# Converting Spring DXA Webapp to Spring Boot APP

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

Our requirement is very simple we would like to create a Spring boot microservice and would like to fetch the content from Tridion.

We have identified 2 ways of doing it

- Either add minimal DXA dependency and configuration to spring boot
  project and fetch content
- Convert DXA-WebApp to spring boot project    and our changes on top
  of it.

We decided to go with latter option as there were some configuration file and some standard dxa code which already works. We added spring boot dependencies and in the main class implemented the WebApplicationInitializer to pick up the configuration but we keep getting the following exception. Please find attached POM and Main class.
following exception and hit a roadblock

> 14:36:03.265 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.BootApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/sdl/web/content/controller/ContentV2Controller.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Can you please tell us if we go with first option (add minimal DXA dependency and configuration to spring boot project) what will be the configuration required or how to fix the above error ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
    <artifactId>dxawebapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>DXA - Webapp</name>
    <description>Example web application for DXA</description>
    <url>http://www.sdl.com/cxc/digital-experience/web-experience-management/digital-experience-accelerator.html</url>

    <properties>
        <dxa-bom.version>1.7.0</dxa-bom.version>
        <dxa-release-branch>release/1.7</dxa-release-branch>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:sdl/dxa-web-application-java.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:sdl/dxa-web-application-java.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>



    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>github-project-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/${dxa-release-branch}/local-project-repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>local-project-repo</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/../local-project-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>core-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-core</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>cid-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-cid</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>search-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-search</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>context-expressions-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-context-expressions</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>googleanalytics-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-googleanalytics</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mediamanager-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-mediamanager</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>smarttarget-web8-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-smarttarget-web8</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>51degrees-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-51degrees</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>audience-manager-web8-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-audience-manager-web8</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test-module</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dxa-module-test</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>  

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
                <artifactId>dxa-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${dxa-bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sdl.dxa.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>dxa-bom-modules</artifactId>
                <version>${dxa-bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SDL Digital Experience Accelerator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-common-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-common-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-web8-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-tridion-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.dxa/dxa-data-model -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-data-model</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-CTP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.dxa/dxa-dd4t-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-dd4t-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-CTP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.dxa/dxa-compatible -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-compatible</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-CTP1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.dxa/dxa-r2-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
            <artifactId>dxa-r2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-CTP1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Main Class

```
    package com;

import static com.sdl.webapp.common.util.InitializationUtils.loadActiveSpringProfiles;
import static com.sdl.webapp.common.util.InitializationUtils.registerListener;
import static com.sdl.webapp.common.util.InitializationUtils.registerServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import com.sdl.dxa.dxawebapp.SpringInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class}) 
public class BootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        //log.debug("Initializing servlet application context");
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        // register webapp spring configuration
        servletAppContext.register(SpringInitializer.class);

        //log.debug("Registering Spring ContextLoaderListener");
        registerListener(servletContext, new ContextLoaderListener(servletAppContext));

        //log.debug("Registering Spring DispatcherServlet");
        registerServlet(servletContext, new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext), "/").setLoadOnStartup(1);

        loadActiveSpringProfiles(servletContext, servletAppContext);
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do the same that the DXA team is doing with the 2.0 release? https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/releases/tag/DXA_2.0_CTP_1_Release

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if I'm getting your initial question correct: you want a spring boot microservice which serves the content from Tridion? But then you continue on asking why your proposed solution is not working?

If I got your initial question right, I think it makes sense looking into another option on solving this. Since DXA is designed to be a web application and I'm not sure how "easy" it is to convert it to a spring boot microservice, which serves just content (besides the fact that DXA does a whole lot more than just serving content, so your microservice might be a bit on the heavy side).

If you take a look at https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service you see the source code of the Model Service which is currently in development for DXA 2.0. At current this isn't really a model service yet, but more a content service (since it doesn't do model mapping yet). But it sounds like it might be very close to what you are looking for, a Spring boot content service.

If you are considering using this, please note, that DXA 2.0 is currently in progress and not released yet. More information about the CTP 1 release of DXA 2.0 can be found in the following blog posts:

- https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/b/product-announcements/posts/sdl-releases-the-first-sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-0-community-technology-preview
- https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/dxa-2-0-architecture

And in the online documentation: https://docs.sdl.com/SDLDXA2-CTP

Answer (score 0):

We will need this functionality. @Abhishek Galoda have you done that? We need that our app API services consume data linked to the page, and we only see these possibilities as the best ones.

Comment: Nope, we just kept the DXA app as spring MVC app.

Comment: oks. So what would be the recommended architectural approach in order to serve static content to a mobile app. I mean to serve content linked to a page.